# Replacing a string placeholder with an actual value in an XML file

Tags: xml, linux

I would like to replace a string in my xml file to an IP adress:
String is : `$IP$`; IP address: `100.100.19.56`, this is the line which the `$IP$` is found at:

```
<attribute name= "IP" assType = "1" tag = "8">$IP$</attribute>
```

I have tried to use : `sed -i 's/$IP$/100.100.19.56/g' filename.xml`, but it doesn't work.

I also tried it this way: `sed -i 's/"$IP$"/100.100.19.56/g' filename.xml`. also didn't work.

what am I doing wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are doing wrong is: You are trying to use regular expressions on XML. Don't do that. Not in this case, and not in any other case, ever.

Comment: thank you @Tomalak. but then again, what should I do instead to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix, you can use `sed` something as below to make it work -

`$ sed -i -e "s/>\$IP\$</>100.100.19.56</g" filename.xml`

PS - As @Tomalak explained, consider using XML aware tools for long run.

Comment: Not only for the long run. *Always*. Those "quick fixes" never get replaced because they seem to work so well, until they don't. This is sloppy and unnecessary. Use the right tools for the right work.

Comment: Surely. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: But i will take @Tomalak advice under consideration. Thank you again

Comment: @EliasShourosh No, you won't.

Comment: Yeah, we have to :-) . I am using `sed` to manipulate a JSON file but now I have thought of replacing it with `jq`. Thanks @Tomalak

Comment: Word boundaries are completely unnecessary here (>, <). Also, you should explain why $ has to be escaped..

Answer (score 2):

XML files are not simply text files. Using `sed` (or and other kind of string-replace functionality) on them is fundamentally wrong.

Use a tool that is aware of how XML works and won't make the mistakes that `sed` will gladly make. One example of an XML-aware tool under Linux is `xmlstarlet`. Another powerful one is `xmlsh` ([homepage](http://www.xmlsh.org/HomePage)).

In `xmlstarlet` you can select a certain node in the XML with XPath and set that node's value.

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//attribte[@name="IP"]' -v '100.100.19.56' filename.xml
```

The operation is not more difficult than using `sed`, but the approach is a hundred times better.

Todo:

- Read about XPath if you are unfamiliar.
- Look at the `xmlstarlet` man page to give yourself an overview of what the tool can do. It's very versatile and worth knowing about.
- You can also browse the [[xmlstarlet]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) tag here on SO to get a look at a couple of examples.